# Connecting Multiple SQL Databases using INI File in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ini

I am having below mention code I am using it for connect only one database .But in order to Connect the multiple database How should I do the corrections Consider I am having two databases Databse "**ABC**" AND Database"**XYZ**"

```
 Imports System.Windows.Forms
 Imports System.IO 
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim File1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\Conn.ini"
Dim Connection = "Connections"
Dim sname = "sname"
Dim Dbase = "Dbase"
Dim Uname = "uname"
Dim Password = "password"
Dim servername = ReadIni(File1, Connection, sname, "")
Dim database = ReadIni(File1, Connection, Dbase, "")
Dim usname = ReadIni(File1, Connection, Uname, "")
Dim pwd = ReadIni(File1, Connection, Password, "")
Dim conn As New SqlConnection
Dim CMD, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3 As New SqlCommand
Dim str As String = "Data Source='" & servername & "' ;Initial Catalog='"      & database & "' ;User Id='" & usname & "';Password='" & pwd & "'"


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn.ConnectionString = str
    conn.Open()
    CMD.Connection = conn
End Sub
```

Comment: A .config file is better suited to this task. Why do you want to use a .INI file?

Comment: Its Old Project in order to change the basic i have to change whole thing thats why i am going in existing set up only

Comment: At least look at the Connection String Builders.

Comment: Is there any simpler way to make changes in existing one

Comment: If you need to keep many connection strings in your INI file then you should give different names to your ini sections. For example "Connection1", "Connection2" then build a method that returns a Dictionary<string,ConnectionData> where the key is the name of the connection and connectionData is a class where you store the data loaded by the ini files.